# How to construct a CString/std::string from a string position

Tags: c++, cstring, stdstring

Given the following:

```
for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); )
{
        CString strFind = line.c_str();
        int n = strFind.ReverseFind( '\\' );

        CString s = CString( strFind,n );

        cout << s << endl;
      // m_Path.push_back( line.c_str() );  
}
```

It is reading a .ini configuration and on this .ini I have a line:

C:\Downloads\Insanity\Program\7. World.exe

this line is added to the `vector<CString>`.

My problem is`int n = strFind.ReverseFind( '\\\' );` finds the string pos of the first \ searching from the end of the string to the beginning, after when constructing a CString like this `CString s = CString( strFind,n );` I'm constructing the FIRST n characters on the string so `s` is equal `C:\Downloads\Insanity\Program` but what I want is to copy `7 .World.exe` to the CString `s` and not the other way, how can I do that using `CString` or `std::string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you converting the `std::string` to a `CString` only for the `ReverseFind` functionality? If so, you can use [`std::basic_string::find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s(R"(C:\Downloads\Insanity\Program\7. World.exe)");

  auto pos = s.find_last_of( '\\' ) + 1; //advance to one beyond the backslash
  std::string filename( s, pos );
  std::cout << filename << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
CString s = strFind.Mid(n+1);
```

or:

```
std::string s = line.substr(n+1);
```